# Can anyone elaborate on how to implement an attribute like local_defines in C++ rules?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I am developing a customized bazel rule and I need an attribute to be applied to the target only, not its dependencies. It should be the same as C++ local_defines. Can anyone provide some ideas on how to implement it? Do I need a dictionary in providers?